# How to resolve a missing contraint within osgi bundles?

Tags: dependencies, osgi, bundle, rcp

```
The bundle ... could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Required-Bundle: ...; bundle-version...
```

I have a RCP Application with several bundles. Now I am trying to create some JUnit Plugin Tests in eclipse in order to test my application. But then I always get the described error, so that the application does not start. But the described bundle, which obviously cannot be resolved is included inside the Manifest file of the concerning bundle. Also the compilation of the bundle which cannot resolve the dependency runs without errors.

Has anybody a further idea in order to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have written something strange in your manifest: you have a dependency on a bundle called "...". Assuming that the bundle "..." doesn't exist, then you should remove this Require-Bundle entry from your manifest.